# How to trigger cross region Lambda function using S3 event notification when S3 and Lambda are in different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

**Scenario:**

1. We have a S3 bucket in Region 1 (e.g. Oregon)
2. We have a Lambda function in Region 2 (e.g. Frankfurt)
3. We have configured S3 to send event notification whenever object is added to the bucket

**Problem:**

We need to invoke the Lambda which is in Region 2 using the S3 event notification which is generated in Region 1.
We are aware that cross account S3 event configuration with Lambda is allowed. But how to implement cross Region event and lambda invocation!

**What we are thinking:**

We thought of using SNS in between S3 and Lambda, but not sure if there is any other alternative available or is this the only way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the most straightforward approach is use SNS in the middle:

1. Region1 S3 notification has a Region1 SNS Topic Destination
2. Region2 Lambda has a [cross-region subscription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-cross-region-delivery.html) to the Region1 SNS Topic

S3 cannot send notifications directly cross-region.

You could also have S3 replicate the created items to Region2, at which point Region2 S3 can directly notify the Region2 Lambda, which may work if the items are small and latency not a big problem.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev, I think replication is not an option due to compliance reasons, but one more question, is there any limit on number of SNS my Lambda can subscribe to? I mean if I created S3 buckets in 10 different regions and will it be possible to route all S3 events to one single Lambda?

Comment: Glad to help!  There is no [documented limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) on lambda subscriptions.